# SSRS Report Viewer Support on Safari

Tags: google-chrome, reporting-services, safari, reportviewer, report-viewer2010

I found this matrix for browser support: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms251673.aspx.  I'm looking for something more updated to include Safari 5 and Chrome.  Is Safari 5 supported in the same way that Safari 4 is as per this document, or is it not officially supported?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Report Viewer 2010 SP 1 works on Safari 5 with the correct document type.